# QStyledItemDelegate custom colors for some elements

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a QStyledItemDelegate with custom painting.  Each item comprises some text and a progress bar.  The progress bar is circular (radial) so it is custom-drawn too: [image]

Also my application uses QSS for some custom styling.
This item delegate was used in a QListView.
I want be able to set different ProgressBar chunk colors for 100% and non-100% with QSS.
**Question**
Is there any way to know color for progress bar chunk for current QSS?

Investigation and code I've tried:

QSS:

```
QProgressBar { border: 1px solid #909090; ; }

QProgressBar[value="100"]::chunk { 
    width: 10px; 
    margin: 0.5px; 
    background-color: rgb(50,145,212);
}

QProgressBar::chunk { 
    width: 10px; 
    margin: 0.5px; 
    background-color: rgb(81,211,49);
}
```

C++:

```
QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 pbStyleOption;
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<QProgressBar> pb(new QProgressBar());
    pb->setStyle(QApplication::style());
    pb->setStyleSheet(static_cast<QApplication*>(QApplication::instance())->styleSheet());
    pb->setValue(progressPercentage);
    pb->setMaximum(100);
    pbStyleOption.initFrom(pb);
    qDebug() << pbStyleOption.palette.brush(QPalette::Highlight);
}
```

I'm using `QPalette::Highlight` because I looked into Qt's source for styles and it uses this ColorRole for `PE_IndicatorProgressChunk`.

**P.S.**
QSS above works only for a slightly modified `QProgressBar`. The only modification is a reimplemented `setValue()`. Here is its code:

```
void StyledProgressBar::setValue(int val)
{
    QProgressBar::setValue(val);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);
    update();
}
```